# Laravel Mailgun Unable to send an email: 404 page not found

Tags: php, laravel, email, driver, mailgun

I'm trying to use mailgun in laravel 9 but I always get this error:

Symfony\Component\Mailer\Exception\HttpTransportException: Unable to send an email: 404 page not found

My env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=xxxxxxx
MAILGUN_SECRET=xxxxxxx
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

My mail.php

```
'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'mailgun'),
```

My services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
        'scheme' => 'https',
    ],
```

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36703657/laravel-404-not-found-error-when-sending-an-email-to-mailgun

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "tls" with "starttls" for your MAIL_ENCRYPTION value

```php
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=starttls
```